# Couldn't find Consumer method in oauth2

Tags: python, twitter, oauth-2.0

I am  trying to connect to twitter api using oauth2. But the code is not working as it shows the error **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Consumer'** 
Is there any update in the oauth2 package? If there is, then what is the another way to do same?

```
def oauth_req(self, url, http_method="GET", post_body=None,
                http_headers=None):`enter code here`
    config = self.parse_config()
    consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=config.get('consumer_key'), secret=config.get('consumer_secret'))
    token = oauth.Token(key=config.get('access_token'), secret=config.get('access_token_secret'))
    client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)

    resp, content = client.request(
        url,
        method=http_method,
        body=post_body or '',
        headers=http_headers
    )
    return content
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Curious, do you have to write the oauth yourself.  It can be tricky if you're new to programming (and even if your not).  You can try using https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI (there are also many others out there) which is a wrapper for the twitter API.  Since its open source you can also see how Auth with handled by the author.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I will definitely try that. But everywhere I am finding a solution which has the consumer() method used with oauth2. But it shows me the error. Is the oauth2 updated with something else?